# RPATH in embedded binary: image not found while path is Okay

Tags: matlab, embedded, rpath

Since DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH is ignored when SIP is active I am trying to use @rpath instead.
I understood that one can add several @rpath and that the system will try all of them successively to find the library.
I also understood that RPATHs propagate from loader to libraries and dependencies.
Am I right ?

Unfortunately all my attempts to use RPATH failed so far.
The auxiliary binary (**embedded binary**) "grasp" tries to access libraries located in a folder external to the bundle (see a description of the bundle at the end).

Here the environment variable which works if SIP is not used:

DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="."
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/Applications/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v911/runtime/maci64"
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/Applications/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v911/bin/maci64"
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/Applications/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v911/sys/os/maci64"

Here at the bottom, the RPATH I added to the binary "grasp" using command:

```
install_name_tool -add_rpath <absolute path> grasp

otool -L grasp.app/Contents/MacOS/grasp
    @rpath/libmwlaunchermain.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)

otool -l grasp.app/Contents/MacOS/grasp | grep -B 1 -A 2 LC_RPATH
Load command 19
          cmd LC_RPATH
      cmdsize 32
         path @loader_path (offset 12)      <-- present in the original binary
--
--
Load command 20
          cmd LC_RPATH
      cmdsize 32
         path @loader_path/. (offset 12)      <-- present in the original binary
--
--
Load command 24
          cmd LC_RPATH
      cmdsize 64
         path /Applications/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v911/bin/maci64 (offset 12)
```

Nonetheless I still get the error message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libmwlaunchermain.dylib
  Referenced from: grasp.app/Contents/MacOS/grasp
  Reason: image not found
```

I thought that

> @rpath/libmwlaunchermain.dylib

would resolve to the path to the library

> /Applications/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v911/bin/maci64/libmwlaunchermain.dylib

Why does this fails?
Is this due to "grasp" being an auxiliary binary?
How can I debug that?

Bundle organisation:

```
Grasp4Mac.app
    Contents
        MacOS/mylauncher  <-- launches grasp.app
    Resources
        Grasp/graps.app    <-- embedded bundle
            Contents
                MacOS
                    applauncher <-- main
                    prelaunch
                    grasp  <-- auxiliary binary calling the libraries
```

Comment: I went one step further.
I added the same RPATH to the "prelaunch" binary which is the main of the bundle "grasp.app" (Sorry for the mistake in my previous post)
Now the library "libmwlaunchermain.dylib" is found but NOT its dependencies.
The number of libraries being in excess of 3000 I cannot modify them.
What shall I do ?

Comment: I also found the DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES environment variable to track library loading. Unfortunately it makes the application hang after loading about 900 libs (MatLab has more than 3000) probably because the output string is too long.

Comment: When the RPATHs are used, the app loads 300 libs and then complains on a library successfully loaded at the very beginning
 ### Error: Could not find version 9.11 of the MATLAB Runtime.
 ### Attempting to load libmwmclmcrrt.9.11.dylib.       <-- at least it does not say "not found"!
I am completely lost !